# nullptr and new keyword

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

I'm learning C++ and kind of confused why the instructor keeps initializing a pointer to `nullptr` instead of just directly allocate memory on the heap

```
int *new_storage {nullptr};
new_storage = new int[size];
```

why cant he just do:

```
int *new_storage = new int[size];
```

is there any advantage of initializing a pointer to `nullptr` prior to memory allocation?

Comment: The two are equivalent.

Comment: *is there any advantage of ...* - There is a **disadvantage**: you can't make `new_storage` `const` in that case.

Comment: In C++ initialization is very special, having all sorts of exceptions and rules. Using assignment as a substitute for initialization is bad form.

Comment: It's always better to initialize a variable(If it's defined in a specific/global scope that you're not going to allocate memory there, the initial value should be `nullptr`. Otherwise, of course you can directly allocate memory safely). An uninitialized pointer stores an undefined value. So, assign `nullptr`. Additionally, considering that you're new to c++, knowing these may be useful: Either `nullptr` or `NULL` both equal are to 0. One more thing, be careful with delete operator. As it does not set the variable back to `nullptr`. Deleted pointer to object will always have an invalid address.

Comment: If those two lines aren't put together, then initialized the pointer to `nullptr` is better. At least you would get segmentation fault quickly in runtime. However if it's a stack variable, I don't see the point the split into two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Instructors are people and they have their own habits. Doing it the second way is considered better by just about everyone, and if you asked him or her about it, you'd probably get agreement.

Of course, get this use of raw pointers out of your system. You need to know how it works, but modern C++ uses smart pointers. You'll want to transition to them as soon as you can do everything using raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

While you are learning any skill, it can be useful to take small steps. The challenge for every instructor is to figure out how small these steps should be.

In this case, I would agree with you: this is overdoing "small steps". But the bigger critique is that the instructor is teaching `new[]` to beginners. For the last 25 years or so, the recommended simple approach is `std::vector<int>`.

In a follow-up course, an instructor could teach how to use `new[]` to implement your own `Vector` class, but that should be for students who can already use `std::vector<int>`.